# Intent to open PDF instantly closes before showing the file

Tags: java, android, pdf, android-intent

I am using the following code to open a specific file I have placed in my working app module...

```
private void openPDF(String filename) {

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), filename);
    Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);

    Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

    pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");

    try {
        startActivity(pdfIntent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There is no PDF file.",
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I get within the `try-statement` and the `startActivity(...)` method is invoked. I get a dialog to choose which app I want to open the file in, but when I choose the app, Android will open the app, display the correct filename within the app, but then will automatically close the PDF app before the file is actually displayed.

**How do I go about keeping the PDF file open until the user decides to actually "close" it?**

By the way, I get no error messages and no warnings that I can see. The PDF app just closes. I also, tried to open the file with `Google Custom Tabs` since I already use that in my app, but it didn't open the PDF file (as I kind of expected)

### Update

For implementing `StreamProvider`, I have decided to create a simple extension to `StreamProvider` that will read a unique tag `pdf-path` that will delegate the work to open an `asset` file

Here is the code...

```
public class PdfProvider extends StreamProvider {

    // Special xml path tag that will work for PDFs (or any asset really)
    private static final String PDF_TAG = "pdf-path";

    @Override
    protected String getUriPrefix() { return null; }

    @Override
    protected StreamStrategy buildStrategy(Context context, String tag, String name, String path, HashMap<String, String> attrs) throws IOException {
        if (PDF_TAG.equals(tag)) {
            super.buildStrategy(context, "asset", name, path, attrs);
        }
        return super.buildStrategy(context, tag, name, path, attrs);
    }
}
```

Also, I have the `noCompress` addition to my `gradle` file and the path meta-data...

```
<paths>
    <pdf-path name="resume" path="resume/resume.pdf"/>
</paths>
```

I am confused at how to actually use `PdfProvider`. The documentation seems to have `asset` logic as a second-thought and the demo code for `StreamProvider` is a little convoluted with additional logic that makes it harder to understand the provider aspect.

Comment: Note: I tried to open the document from the app using one of Adobe's apps, and it said `Error: Could not import document` however, I can open the document perfectly fine on my laptop

Comment: "How do I go about keeping the PDF file open until the user decides to actually "close" it?" -- figure out why the PDF viewer cannot view your `Uri`. For example, it may not have permission to read or write external storage. Or the `Uri` might point to something that does not exist. Bear in mind that [using `Uri.fromFile()` is effectively nixed in Android N](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/14/psa-file-scheme-ban-n-developer-preview.html), so you may wish to [switch to a `FileProvider` anyway](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/16/how-publish-files-via-content-uri.html).

Comment: I am working on switching it to `FileProvider`. I knew about this option before, but was using a copy-paste example from other code. However, I don't remember anything about `files-path` before. This is my current problem `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/xyz.pdf at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:678)`

Comment: That would be `external-path`. Despite the documentation, that points to the root of external storage.

Comment: OK, I think I have FileProvider implemented; however, the same issue occurs with the PDF file disappearing. So, I did a check for the existence of the file, and you were right, the file does not exist. Maybe I am doing it completely wrong, but I just drag-and-dropped the file within the app module. Not within the src folder. Is that even right?

Comment: Any solution on this as yet?

Comment: @ChristopherRucinski can you share your solution? I am having the same problem.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am having the same problem, do you maybe have a solution? I am using the FileProvider, and have set up the File provider settings in the Manifest file as well as an .xml file with the paths to use. I am trying to open a .pdf file in external storage, in the Download directory.

Comment: @fobisthename: If you are running Android 10+, you may not have access to the file. I suggest that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide a [mcve] showing how that PDF file is getting where it is and how you are trying to use it. You might also check Logcat to see if there are any useful messages from the app that you are trying to use to view the PDF.

Comment: @CommonsWare yes I am using Android 11. I was actually trying it also on Android 9 to check if it worked, but I get the same behaviour. For Android 9 do I need to explicitly ask the user for read permissions? I am already using the Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_PERMISSION to the intent. Thank you for you answer!

Comment: @fobisthename: "For Android 9 do I need to explicitly ask the user for read permissions?" -- you need `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, including requesting it at runtime.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I just drag-and-dropped the file within the app module. Not within the src folder. Is that even right?

Alas, no. That is your project on your development machine. It is not [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) on ~1.5 billion devices.

If your long-term objective is to actually show a PDF from external storage, put it on external storage of your device or emulator. With the Android Studio 2.x emulator, you can drag and drop the PDF into the emulator window, though that will put it in the `Downloads/` directory of external storage, not the root.

If your long-term objective is to show a PDF that you package with your app, put the PDF in `assets/` of your module's `main` sourceset (e.g., `app/src/main/assets/` in a typical Android Studio project). Then, either:

- use [my `StreamProvider`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider) to serve the PDF straight from there, or
- write code to copy the PDF somewhere on the filesystem (probably [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html)), then use `FileProvider` to serve it, as I demonstrate in [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider)

Comment: Using `Option 2` and changing back to `files-path` works. Thank you. Dealing with grabbing files from the system is still a confusing endeavor for me.

Comment: How do you actually use `StreamProvider` to open up a PDF file in Assets? From your documentation it does not seem clear. Also, the demo has a lot of additional logic intermingled into the code that are not relevant to `StreamProvider`s, so I am confused at how to implement it

Comment: @ChristopherRucinski: Define the XML metadata and define the `<provider>` element in the manifest as outlined [here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider#usage-streamprovider). Then build a `Uri` for your asset using [this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider#getting-uri-values) (which I just added to the docs, thanks for pointing out the gap).

Comment: OK, I updated the question just now, but you might have answered everything now. I will take a look at it